# Could someone help me identify this button from a WW2 prison camp field?

Tags: world-war-two, military, war, identification

I'm struggling to identify a button found in a field in Italy, where WW2's prison camps were built.
Searching online I found a lot of American's Civil War buttons that could be related to it, based on its shape, but I'm not finding any more than that.

Could someone enlighten me or point me to the right path?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that lettering on the thing the eagle is standing on or some floral design?

Comment: I really can't tell, but they don't seem to be letters

Comment: It may help to know if the camp was operated by Italians, ermans or Allied forces, and about when (pre or post '43 would be relevant)

Comment: Might have been operated by allied forces, but that is just a speculation, I don't know much about the place as it is very rural and with pretty much no informations

Comment: I don't believe that is an item of US service uniforms.

Comment: The closest thing I come up with is that it *resembles* a [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Fascist_Party#/media/File:Fascist_Eagle.svg) of the [Italian Fascist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Fascist_Party), an Eagle clutching a [fasces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasces). I just can't quite make the bottom item match a fasces as they are usually represented, I see no axe head.